# sql server: select a NULL field that is foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

table "product" :

```
productID      productNAME
21             mouse
22             keyboard
```

table "order" :

```
orderID      productID
31           21
32           NULL
```

sql command:

```
SELECT dbo.[order].orderID, dbo.product.productNAME
FROM   dbo.[order] 
INNER JOIN dbo.product ON dbo.[order].productID = dbo.product.productID
```

result:

```
orderID      productID
31           mouse
```

QUESTION:
how to show the second order? (while productID of that order is NULL, but that order existed)
is there any trick for that?

i tried these:

```
WHERE (dbo.[order].orderID = 32) OR
      (dbo.product.productID IS NULL)
```

and

```
SELECT dbo.[order].orderID, ISNULL(dbo.product.productNAME, ' - ') AS Expr1
FROM  dbo.[order] 
INNER JOIN dbo.product ON dbo.[order].productID = dbo.product.productID
```

but the same result

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is `left join`:

```
SELECT o.orderID, p.productNAME
FROM dbo.[order] o LEFT JOIN
     dbo.product p
     ON o.productID = p.productID;
```

You could also write:

```
SELECT o.orderID, p.productNAME
FROM dbo.[order] o JOIN
     dbo.product p
     ON o.productID = p.productID OR o.productID IS NULL;
```

The `OR` will probably affect the performance of this query.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using an Inner Join, specifically matched on ProductID. Because one is NULL of course it will not match. If you wish to return all results from the Order table regardless of whether there is a match in the product table, you need to look at other types of Joins, such as LEFT and RIGHT OUTER JOINS.

Answer (score 0):

A classic outer join example!

```
   SELECT dbo.[order].orderID, ISNULL(dbo.product.productNAME, ' - ') AS Expr1
     FROM dbo.[order] 
LEFT JOIN dbo.product ON dbo.[order].productID = dbo.product.productID
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use OR condition along with inner join.

```
SELECT o.orderID
    ,p.productNAME
FROM dbo.[order] o
INNER JOIN dbo.product p ON o.productID = p.productID
    OR o.productID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious/classic solution is `UNION`:

```
SELECT dbo.[order].orderID, dbo.product.productNAME
FROM   dbo.[order] 
INNER JOIN dbo.product ON dbo.[order].productID = dbo.product.productID
UNION
SELECT dbo.[order].orderID, '{{NONE}}' AS productNAME
FROM   dbo.[order] 
WHERE  dbo.[order].productID IS NULL;
```